# keyValue observer from cell to managed object

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, key-value-observing

I am looking at a table view cell here and I find this code:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"model.isDownloading" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"model.isCached" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"model.isOutDated" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"model.cacheUpdateDate" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"model" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
}
```

The observers are removed in the `dealloc` method. `model` is a `weak` property, receiving a managed object (core-data).

I receive spurious crashes, telling me, that the managed object is deleted, but still has observers registered.

Why the error happens is pretty clear to me: The object is removed somewhere in the background, but still linked into the tableview's cell. Since `dealloc` on the cell is basically never called during lifetime of the application, the observers are never really removed. Since the reference to the core-data object is `weak`, it will deallocate silently in the background - at least try to. This fails, because the model is still observed.

I have some questions:

- If a path like "model.isDownloading" is observed, then the observer is registered in the `model` object, not in the setter in `self`, is that correct?
- Is objC smart enough to handle the observer change if `model` is reassigned (`self.model = newThing` requires, that `removeObserver` is called on `model` before assigning `newThing`, and observers need to be registered on `newThing` after that).
- Since the crash happens on dealloc of the managed object, I think a simple solution would be, to make `model` strong instead of `weak`, and of course make sure, that it is properly set to `nil` in `prepareForReuse:`. Does this have side effects, that I have not realized?

The error message is:

`class xxx was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it`

Comment: I thing that the tableview is reusing the cells, maybe try to remove the observers on the method prepareForReuse of the uitableviewcell

Comment: That is not the point. I know that the cell is reused. The model gets set, when the cell is reused. It looks like KVO properly manages this change. Yet, the object vanishes in the background, without the cell realizing. That is why I think that I need to hold on the reference with a `strong` property, not weak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If a path like "model.isDownloading" is observed, then the observer is registered in the `model` object, not in the setter in `self`, is that correct?**

This is a very good question.  As far as I knew previously, the runtime keeps tracks of at least 2 things when an object is registered with KVO
1) The object that **is** observing and
2) the keypath of a property it is observing.

We know the runtime overrides the setter of the property to notify the objects observing of a change.

But clearly the runtime must also keep track of the object that is **being** observed, otherwise how else would it know if it is being released while there are still observers registered?

It appears that the runtime parses the `keyPath` for dots, and follows the reference chain from the receiver (`self` in your example), to keep track of the observed object (`self.model`)

**Is objC smart enough to handle the observer change if `model` is reassigned (`self.model = newThing` requires, that `removeObserver` is called on `model` before assigning `newThing`, and observers need to be registered on `newThing` after that).**

No it is not smart enough.  What happens is that the runtime subclasses your `self.model` object (Let's say it's of type `Model`) to override the setter for `isDownloading`, for example.  Now your `self.model` object is of type `NSKVONotifying_Model`. If you were to swap out your `self.model` pointer to point to a new object of type `Model`, it would not be of the same KVO class that the runtime created.  Thus the setter for the property would not have the instructions added to notify observers.
So yes you have to remove observers on the first object and add it to the second object, even though you are using the same pointer variable.

**Since the crash happens on dealloc of the managed object, I think a simple solution would be, to make `model` strong instead of `weak`, and of course make sure, that it is properly set to `nil` in `prepareForReuse:`. Does this have side effects, that I have not realized?**

This would be correct, but as you know you would have to re-add observers if your referenced `model` object gets swapped out.

Another alternative (if you can change the `Model` class), is to add a reference in the `Model` class back to your `self` in this context.  Then in the `init`/`dealloc` of your `Model` class, you can add itself as an observer to your new reference.

Last note is that if you ever catch yourself sending an `addObserver` message where the receiver **and** the observer object are the same-- you may as well just override the setter yourself.

In your example, you could just override `-setModel` to do whatever you were going to do in your observation notification handler (`-observeValueForKey:::`)

Comment: Thanks, this explains a lot. Yet, I have to keep a strong reference, as I do not get informed if another thread removes the model instance from coredata. The release of that model-instance will trigger the exception. If I dont use a strong reference, the release will happen immediately after delete, but the cell is active on the screen and will be removed during table reload. The strong reference keeps the model around until the table reload completes.